# Programmatically Adding Clickable Image on Web Page

Tags: vb.net, visual-web-developer

I have a help button with a special image I use throughout my project.  Most of the time, I can just add it in the design view with:

```
<img alt="" src="Images/help.jpg" onclick="click_help('foo', 'bar')" class="myHelpClass" style="height: 20px; width: 33px" />
```

and I'll have a javascript script at the bottom of the page to handle `click_help`.  Everything to this part is working as intended.

Now, however, I have a dynamically created table with dynamic cells, and I need to add a help button to one of those cells.  So far, I have this:

```
    Dim help As New HtmlControls.HtmlImage
    help.Src = "Images/help.jpg"
    help.class = "myHelpClass"
    help.Height = 20
    help.Width = 33
    AddHandler help.onClick, AddressOf helpClicked
    cell.Controls.Add(help)
```

This throws 2 errors though:

```
'class' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlImage'.
'onClick' is not an event of 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlImage'.
```

I looked through the hierarchy on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlimage(v=vs.110).aspx), and it looks like neither `class` nor `onClick` appear anywhere.

**So why does the line from the design view above not throw any errors (in fact, they are fully functional, as I mentioned above - the onClick code is definitely working)?**

**How do I get the desired functionality with a dynamically created control?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works in the design view because adding classes and onclick events are basic HTML markup, however these aren't properties of the corresponding `HtmlControls.HtmlImage` object type in VB.Net.

For any attributes you want to add that aren't already members of the object, you can simply use `myElement.Attributes.Add("attribute-name", "attribute value")`

```
Dim help As New HtmlControls.HtmlImage
help.Src = "Images/help.jpg"
help.Height = 20
help.Width = 33
help.Attributes.Add("class","myHelpClass")
help.Attributes.Add("onclick","click_help('foo', 'bar');")
cell.Controls.Add(help)
```

Comment: Thanks for the 'basic HTML markup' bit, I didn't know that!